# MongoDB Update Array using php

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb, mongodb-query

When I use rockmongo to modify document, I use the following:

critria:

```
array (
  'friends.50e6b194f028b9790b000002' => 
  array (
    '$exists' => true,
  ),
)
```

New Object:

`array ( '$set' => 
                                      array (
                                        'friends.$.50e6b194f028b9790b000002.info' => "blablabla",
                                      ),
                                    )`

It's work fine.

In php:

```
    $collection->update(array('friends.'.$val =>  array (
                                    '$exists' => true,
                                  )),
                    array ( '$set' => 
                                  array (
                                    'friends.$.'.$val.'.info' => "blablabla",
                                  ),
                                ) );
```

Not work.

What's wrong in php? The $val = 50e6b194f028b9790b000002

Comment: create a mongodb shell script to do the job, then make it work in PHP.  and I cannot understand your purpose. wanna update some specified element in an array, which is a property of a document?

Comment: Right. I need to update some element in array. I created criteria and new object for mongodb shell script, actually I used rockmongo for this, but my problem is to make it work in php

Comment: maybe you should change your data schema. if the array property is not logically equivalent, it's better to split them into several documents which are stored seperated.

Comment: may be, but if it works via rockmongo or via shell it should work from php.

Comment: known little on PHP, sorry...

Comment: Given that you're using the [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/#_S_), the update should set the first matched array position from the query. In your example, that's going to be the first element of the `friends` array that has a `val` field present. You will need to elaborate on what exactly isn't working. I'd also suggest reporting the return value of the update operation when using a write concern of 1 (to check the getLastError response).